# Azure IoT Hub: Configure Managed Identity via Powershell cmdlets

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-iot-hub

I create an Azure IoT Hub with Powershell cmdlets, using `New-AzIotHub`, somewhat similar to [this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-create-using-powershell)

I want to use managed identity (system assigned) for my endpoints, and I can configure it properly in the Azure Portal:
[image: Azure Portal to config Managed Identity]

Looking through [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.iothub/new-aziothub?view=azps-8.1.0), I couldn't find anything, how to activate managed identity for my iot hub **via Powershell**? Has anyone an idea how to achieve that or where to find infos for that?

Comment: Is there a specific requirement would you prefer PowerShell instead of Azure Portal or CLI? If you are ok to use CLI, see here [az iot hub identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub/identity?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-hub-identity-assign)

Comment: Yes, our current iac-framework is based on az Powershell and I don't want to rewrite it ;)